# Textview responsive margin/padding

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

It seems like my Android design is having a problem. Here is the problem:

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOJlH.png)

As you can see, "http ://LABEL 2 GOES HERE" is right on top of the label 1 text: "This is just a test for label 1......." How can I make it so that the "http ://LABEL 2 GOES HERE" will always be below "label 1" 30dp no matter how long or short it is?

How can I make it so that

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      android:minHeight="1000dp">

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="About:"
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Website:"
        android:id="@+id/website"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

      <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:autoLink="web"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you include the XML that you already for this.

Comment: @buczek I just edited the OP with the XML code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a relative layout as root element and use android:layout_below id of your last label on label 2. And add android:layout_marginTop on label 2 and you should be good to go.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to lay everything below the actual description. Here is something I did that should work for you.

[image]

Increased size

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About:"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/aboutDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/about"
        android:text="Description \n description"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/website"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Website:"
        android:layout_below="@id/aboutDescription"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/websiteDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/website"
        android:layout_below="@id/aboutDescription"
        android:text="Description \n description"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for

Take a linear layout in parent and 2 different Relative layout for different lines(not necessary)

Relative Layout have height wrap content so it will increase decrease according to your size of data .

[image]

Here is Code :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="About :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/about"
        android:text="This is just a test for lebel 1 \nThis is just a test for lebel 1 \nThis is just a test for lebel 1 \nThis is just a test for lebel 1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/website"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Website :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/website"
        android:minLines="4"
        android:text="This is just a test for lebel 2 \nThis is just a test for lebel 2 \nThis is just a test for lebel 2 \nThis is just a test for lebel 2 \nThis is just a test for lebel 2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textSize="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout></LinearLayout>
```